# How to read from a .txt file into an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following sample data in a .txt file

```
111, Sybil, 21
112, Edith, 22
113, Mathew, 30
114, Mary, 25
```

the required output is

```
[{"number":"111","name":"Sybil","age":"21" },
{"number":"112","name":"Edith","age":"22"},
{"number":"113","name":"Mathew","age":"30"},
"number":"114","name":"Mary","age":"25"]
```

Sadly, I have not gone far because I cant seem to get the values out of each line. instead, this is what is displayed

[one, two, three]

```
    private void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File txt = new File("Users.txt");
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(txt)) {
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>() ;
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                
                data.add(scan.nextLine());
                 System.out.print(scan.nextLine()); 
            }
             System.out.print(data); 
               
            
        }
```

I would appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not too sure about the requirements. If you just need to know how to get the values out, then use `String.split()` combined with `Scanner.nextLine()`.

Codes below:

```
    private void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File txt = new File("Users.txt");
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(txt)) {
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            // split the data by ", " and split at most (3-1) times
            String[] input = scan.nextLine().split(", ", 3);
            data.add(input[0]);
            data.add(input[1]);
            data.add(input[2]);

            System.out.print(scan.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.print(data);
    }
}
```

The output would be as below and you can further modify it yourself:

```
[111, Sybil, 21, 112, Edith, 22, 113, Mathew, 30, 114, Mary, 25]
```

However, if you need the required format as well, the closest I can get  is by using a `HaspMap` and put it into the `ArrayList`.

Codes below:

```
    private void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File txt = new File("Users.txt");
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(txt)) {
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            // Create a hashmap to store data in correct format,
            HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap();
            String[] input = scan.nextLine().split(", ", 3);
            info.put("number", input[0]);
            info.put("name", input[1]);
            info.put("age", input[2]);
            
            // Put it inside the ArrayList
            data.add(info);
        }
        System.out.print(data);
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
[{number=111, name=Sybil, age=21}, {number=112, name=Edith, age=22}, {number=113, name=Mathew, age=30}, {number=114, name=Mary, age=25}]
```

Hope this answer helps you well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're skipping lines. A quote from the `Scanner::nextLine` documentation:

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So you're adding one line to your list, and writing the next one to the console.

To get the data from each line, you can use the `String::split` method, which supports *RegEx*.

*Example:*

```
"line of my file".split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use streams to write some compact code.

First we define a `record` to hold our data.

`Files.lines` reads your file into memory, producing a stream of strings, one per line.

We call `Stream#map` to produce another stream, a series of string arrays. Each array has three elements, the three fields within each line.

We call `map` again, this time to produce a stream of `Person` objects. We construct each person object by parsing and passing to the constructor each of line’s three fields.

We call `Stream#toList` to collect those person objects into a list.

We call `List#toString` to generate text representing the contents of the list of person objects.

```
record Person ( int id , String name , int age ) {}
String output = 
    Files
    .lines( Paths.of("/path/to/Users.txt" ) )
    .map( line -> line.split( ", " ) )
    .map( parts -> new Person( 
        Integer.parseInt( parts[ 0 ] ) , 
        parts[ 1 ] ,
        Integer.parseInt( parts[ 2 ] ) 
    ) )
    .toList()
    .toString() 
;
```

If the format of the default `Person#toString` method does not suit you, add an override of that method to produce your desired output.